# MSBuild running on other platform after specifying platform:x64 - Azure pipelines

Tags: msbuild

I have dotnet solution having multiple .vcxproj and .csproj.

Also it is having the configurations like below

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Debug|ARM = Debug|ARM
    Debug|ARM64 = Debug|ARM64
    Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
    Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    Release|ARM = Release|ARM
    Release|ARM64 = Release|ARM64
    Release|x64 = Release|x64
    Release|x86 = Release|x86
    SELFHOST|Any CPU = SELFHOST|Any CPU
    SELFHOST|ARM = SELFHOST|ARM
    SELFHOST|ARM64 = SELFHOST|ARM64
    SELFHOST|x64 = SELFHOST|x64
    SELFHOST|x86 = SELFHOST|x86
EndGlobalSection
```

I am running the Visual studio build in Azure build pipeline by specifying the platform = x64.

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build the Solution
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(SolutionFile)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:TargetPlatformVersion=$(TargetPlatformVersion) /p:LatestTargetPlatformVersion=$(TargetPlatformVersion) /p:Prefer32bit=false'
    platform: 'x64'
    configuration: 'Debug'
    clean: true
    maximumCpuCount: true
    logProjectEvents: false
    createLogFile: true
    logFileVerbosity: 'diagnostic'
```

I'm see the logs with below messages

```
Building solution configuration "Debug|x64"
====Other Logs===== 
Building solution configuration "Debug|x86"
```

I'm wondering why it is building on "Debug|x86" after specifying platform: 'x64'.

Any help would be appreciated?

Regards,

Naresh Ede

Comment: Hi @Naresh Ede,
Please try with the following steps to see if the same behavior occurs:
1. Specify the **`Platform`** and **`Configuration`** using **MSBuild Arguments** (e.g. **`/p:Platform='x64' /p:Configuration='Debug'`**).
2. Build you solution on your local machine with [**MSBuild command-line**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019) (e.g. **`MSBuild.exe [ProjectFile] -p:Platform='x64';Configuration='Debug'. . .`**).

Comment: Thanks for checking.
I tried the below command
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "C:\w\538\s\Solution.sln" /p:platform="x64" /p:configuration="Release"`

As I have many projects in my solution and dependencies on each project. I tried specifying solution name instead of project name.

And still seeing the solution running on Debug|x86.

Comment: Hi @Naresh Ede,
Due to the same problem also occurs on local MSBuild, the problem should not be related to Azure DevOps and Azure Pipelines.
Looks like, the problem is related to the configuration settings on your solution or the projects in the solution.
Does the extra Building solution configuration with x86 occur on all the projects, or only on a specific project in the solution?
If it only occurs on a specific project, for us to investigate this problem further, could you please share the project file with us?